# How to properly inject bean in Spring boot for a service genearted with with apache cxf?

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, cxf, jax-ws, wsdl2java

I am trying to implement a client for Soap Web Service. I have a Spring boot application and I generated classes from wsdl using apache cxf. Somehow I have problems to inject the bean correctly and use its method. This is my code:

Configuration class:

```
@Bean(name = "myApiClient")
public GeneratedService myApiClient(MyCredentials credentials) {
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean jaxWsProxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setServiceClass(GeneratedService.class);
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setAddress(getUrl());
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setUsername(credentials.getUser());
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setPassword(credentials.getPassword());

    return (GeneratedService) jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create();
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    GeneratedService myApiClient;

    @Autowired
    public MyServiceImpl(GeneratedService myApiClient) {
        this.myApiClient = myApiClient;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MyObject> someMethod() {
        return myApiClient.someApiMethod();
    }
}
```

The error I get:

> Parameter 0 of constructor MyServiceImpl required a bean of type
> '...GeneratedService' that could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try inject service with `@Autowired` tag or `@Resource` tag.

```java
    @Autowired
    GeneratedService myApiClient;
```

```java
    @Resource(name="myApiClient")
    GeneratedService myApiClient;
```